# DocuSign - Need to downgrade replacement CoSign Central appliance to version 5.2

Tags: docusignapi, cosign-api

We recently received an ARX device to replace a failed unit. The issue is that it has version 6 installed and we have a legal requirement to keep it version 5.2. 
Is it possible to downgrade to version 5.2 from version 6? And, if so, what is the link to version 5.2. Otherwise, how do we request a specific version on the replacement device?

Comment: Please contact [CoSign Central support](http://www.arx.com/contactform/support-request/). They'll help you out.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately, they are the ones that said I had to "contact the developers at stack overflow and see if they respond"

Comment: Did you use the CoSign (arx.com) form I referenced in my comment above? Please confirm. If so, I will follow up with the support people to learn more. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

StackOverflow won't be able to help you on this one. Please [Contact ARX Support](http://www.arx.com/contactform/support-request/) for assistance.